# Is using a loading observable toggle for observables necessary?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Some of the container templates I'm looking at load data like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(loading$ | async); else tpl">
```

Whenever the client is fetching data (Say `Post` ) instances, it will set the `loading$` observable to emit false, and when the `Observable<Post[]>`s become available then it will set `loading$` to true.

In this case it seems like we could simply substitute the `loading$` with `posts$`, since the `*ngIf` will evaluate to `false` until the `Observable<Post[]>` is ready to emit?

So in other words we don't really need `loading$` - we could just use `posts$` instead?

When the `posts$` Observable is ready the container will show the `posts` iterated through like this:

```
 <post *ngFor="let post of (post$ | async)" [post]="post"></post>
```

Comment: ng-container doesn't put inside the DOM whereas post might or might not be populated inside the DOM (depends on post template). so loading$ occurs and automatically show in pages. Post might already be loaded before there is data. if this not ng-container, then the other ng-container.

Comment: I'm assuming `posts$` will evaluate to false until the `posts[]` is available, at which point angular will not show the `tpl` and will show the posts rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading means you are waiting for the response from the server, what about the case where the response that comes back is no posts. In this case you don't want to show loading but instead a message that there are no posts.

Comment: IIUC we could just create an array with zero posts within the service receiving the posts, if for some reason the server does not do it?  Allthough I do think that perhaps the `loading$` semantics are a bit cleaner.

Comment: Using a loading flag is much clearer and you are not saving much by recycling a single object.